# How can I filter a list in struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts

The array list i am creating and passing to my jsp is

```
ArrayList countryList = new ArrayList();
countryList.add(new CountryData("1", "USA"));
countryList.add(new CountryData("2", "Canada"));
countryList.add(new CountryData("3", "Mexico"));
countryList.add(new CountryData("4", "Canada"));
```

on jsp page i am displaying using

```
<html:select property="country" >
<html:option value="0">Select Country</html:option>
<html:optionsCollection name="InputForm" property="countryList"
label="countryName" value="countryId" />
</html:select>
```

Is it possible filtering the list on jsp to show only canada in drop down

Comment: You should do the filtering in your java code instead of in the JSP.

Comment: the filtering depends on value entered by user in another feild

Comment: I think that doesn't make any difference. In any case you should do the filtering with javascript once the user has selected a value in that other field.

Comment: I tried reloading the page after user entry--too much overhead. I tried to use ajax to get data and repopulate the select box but couldn't send required arraylist

Comment: I want to do it with javascript but can't figure how i would get the arrayList countryList in javascript and then populate the required selectbox

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is probably to serialize the list of CountryData to JSON (using one of the myriads of free Java JSON libraries), and to use JavaScript to filter the array of countries.

In Java:

```
String countryListAsJSON = serialize(countryList);
request.setAttribute("countries", countryListAsJSON);
```

In the JSP:

```
<script>
    var countries = ${countries};
    //...
</script>
```

Which will be translated to the following HTML code:

```
<script>
    var countries = [{"countryId": "1", "countryName": "USA"}, {"countryId": "2", "countryName": "Canada"}, ...];
    //...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and there are several ways to do it:

1. using scriptlets: 
   (assuming all needed include directives are done)

   ```
   <%= List<CountryData> newList = new ArrayList<CountryData>(); %>
   <html:select property="country" >
   <html:option value="0">Select Country</html:option>
   <% 
        for(CountryData cd:countryList) {
            if("Canada".equals(cd.getCountry())) {
                newList.add(cd);
            }
        }
   %>
   <html:optionsCollection name="InputForm" property="newList" label="countryName" value="countryId" />
   </html:select>
   ```
2. using JSTL either `c:forEach` or `c:if` tags to filter out all unneeded elements from the list
3. using custom tag specifically developed to filter out all countries except "Canada" from your list